# Use filter in aggregator with condition based on a subdocument value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to filter out `messages` subdocuments of from a `discussion` document, based on a date field in a `deletion` subdocument that I retrieve thanks to a user id

In JavaScript, it would give something as the following (just to clarify)

```
discussion.messages.filter(message => message.createdAt < discussion.deletions[userID].updatedAt)
```

Here is what I have right now:

```
Discussion.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(discussionID),
      participants: userID
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      messages: {
        $slice: [{
          $filter: {
            input: '$messages',
            as: 'message',
            cond: {
              $and: // the filtering condition should be there
            }
          }
        }, limit]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Any idea ?

Here is the details:

```
const DeletionSchema = Schema({
  userID: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
},{
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: true
})

const DiscussionSchema = Schema({
  participants: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }],
  messages: [MessageSchema],
  deletions: [DeletionSchema]
}, {
  timestamps: true
})

const MessageSchema = Schema({
  author: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  text: String
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
```

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc09358355f682571644db5"),
    "participants" : [ 
        ObjectId("5fbdb3c0d1daa832cce7435f"), 
        ObjectId("5fbe92f63bcc731d3d677a26")
    ],
    "__v" : 0,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-11-27T05:49:12.784Z"),
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "deletedAt" : null,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fc09ab7ad6276548b328a43"),
            "author" : ObjectId("5fbe92f63bcc731d3d677a26"),
            "text" : "This one must stay !",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-11-27T06:20:39.803Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-11-27T06:20:39.803Z")
        }, 
        {
            "deletedAt" : null,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fc099a8b4415f528ceabc43"),
            "author" : ObjectId("5fbe92f63bcc731d3d677a26"),
            "text" : "This one must stay !",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-11-27T06:16:08.173Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-11-27T06:16:08.173Z")
        }, 
        {
            "deletedAt" : null,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fc09358efb3374d4e2264be"),
            "author" : ObjectId("5fbe92f63bcc731d3d677a26"),
            "text" : "Hello world",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-11-27T05:49:12.784Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-11-27T05:49:12.784Z")
        }
    ],
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-11-27T06:20:39.803Z"),
    "deletions" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fc095d220928a4eff942652"),
            "userID" : ObjectId("5fbe92f63bcc731d3d677a26"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-11-27T05:59:46.731Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-11-27T05:59:46.731Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

So, if the given `userID` match a `deletions` subdocument, I would like to filter out the `message` who was created after the deletion `createdAt`

Comment: can you please add you schema or sample document.

Comment: I edited the question with all the details :)

Comment: In you client side approach `discussion.deletions[userID].date` how you are accessing this userID's document, you have prepared this structure before this operation and `date` field in not there in your sample document,

Comment: Sorry, the ```discussion.deletions[userID].date``` part is not a real implementation, it was only to demonstrate what I was trying to do, and ```date``` field is a typo, I'm using deletion.updatedAt

Comment: also userID is a given parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$match` filter conditions
- `$addFields` add new field `deletion`, `$filter` to get `userID` object from `deletions` and get first object from that result using `$first`
- `$project` to show required fields, filter `messages` using `$filter` and condition as per date, and `$slice` to get limited messages

```
Discussion.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(discussionID),
      participants: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userID)
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      deletion: {
        $first: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$deletions",
            cond: { $eq: ["$$this.userID", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userID)] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      messages: {
        $slice: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$messages",
              cond: { $lt: ["$$this.createdAt", "$deletion.updatedAt"] }
            }
          },
          limit
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Aud3yIGpPM1)

Comment: ```$first``` wasn't recognized, so I used ```$arrayElemAt``` instead, but it's working very well, thank you a lot !